# OnChange event handler not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using onchange event handler with an input element. I know it's simple, I just added an onchange attribute. But it's not at all working also not showing any kind of error in console.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function select(a) {
    console.log(a);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
  }
</script>
<p id="demo"></p>

<input type="checkbox" onchange="select('XYZ')">
```

Comment: Something to do with the function name `select`.

Comment: Rejith is right, just rename your function

Comment: Could be `select()` function for input's has some effect here.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan : yup thanks mate :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`select` is a [reserved word](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) in JavaScript (sort of).

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function _select(a) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
  }
</script>
<p id="demo"></p>

<input type="checkbox" onchange="_select('XYZ')">
```

---

<sup>Note that, as the link above states, `select` isn't *technically* a reserved word (in *JavaScript*). It can be used in general for variable names and functions. But, browser implementations do refuse to bind DOM events *directly* to functions that share DOM property names. And, I'm not yet  sure where this restriction or conflict is explicitly named in the specs ... or if it's just an unhappy accident.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a list of reserved keywords which cannot be used as function names or variable names.

For a complete list, check this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function select1(a) {
    console.log(a);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
  }
</script>

<input type="checkbox" onchange="select1('XYZ')" name="xyz" value="xyz">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

you should change your function name becouse there is collision occurs that's why it's not working try above