# how to append option to a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a variable which contains a number. I'd like to append an option with the numeric value in each based on whatever the variable number is ( ie: if total equals 10, then I need to add 10 options to the select with each option containing the next numeric row value, so 1, 2, 3, 4...etc. I start off with one hard coded option, and then I need to add options dynamically for every case. I've tried a multitude of scripts but I"m getting " cannot use in operator to search for length.

https://jsfiddle.net/v1yyhfm8/

HTML

```
 <select id="main">
     <option selected>1</option>
 </select>
```

I tried:

```
 var total = dataSource.total();
 for (var i = 1; 1 <= total; i++) {
     var added = document.createElement('option');
     var test = $('#main');
     added.value = i;
     added.innerHTML = i;
     test.append(added);
 }
```

and

```
  var total = dataSource.total();
  $.each(total, function (i, item) {
    $('#main').append($('<option>', {
       value: item.total,
       text: item.text
    }));                               
  });
```

Comment: What is `dataSource.total()` ?

Comment: With `$.each(total`, total should be an array or collection..

Comment: datasource.total() is whatever the number of rows there are in the grid. So  in this case you can use 10.

Comment: @PranavCBalan — `select` is `jQuery` element..

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I took out select and added test, its saying appendChild isn't a function

Comment: Typo:  `1 <= total`, plus jQuery hasn't been added to your fiddle.

Comment: sorry, how is 1 <= total a typo?

Comment: If total is greater than 1, then `1 <= total` will always be true.  I assumed you meant, `i <= total`.

Comment: ahh yes  see, but the result is still the same since i = 1

Comment: @Keith the i++ at the end of that line is what increments i on each time it loops, meaning i won't always be 1

Comment: If I make that change and add jQuery, your fiddle works:  https://jsfiddle.net/f4h2h2c9/

Comment: Further to the other comments, be aware that you can create an `option` element using it's JS api. That is to say, you don't need to call createElement with 'option' as the parameter, followed by setting it's value and displayed text. You can simply write `test.appendChild( new Option(i, i) );`, where the first `i` is the displayed text, and the second is the value of the `value` attribute. Here, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/f4h2h2c9/1/

Comment: @enhzflep that's a very good reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the for loop condition would be true always which leads to an infinite loop so change it to `i <= total`.

```
var total = dataSource.total();
for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
    var added = document.createElement('option');
    var select1 = $('#main');
    added.value = i;
    added.innerHTML = i;
    select1.append(added);
}
```

```js
var total = 10;
for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
  var added = document.createElement('option');
  var select1 = $('#main');
  added.value = i;
  added.innerHTML = i;
  select1.append(added);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="main">
  <option selected>1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yeah says that appendChild is not a function

Comment: yeah i tried test like above and its saying appendChild isn't a function

Comment: i changed it, still says 1 in option box

Comment: Read your own link - `select` is _not_ a reserved keyword

Comment: @Alnitak : `select` is not reserved but it may cause problem .... please check the link..... last year I'd some issue while used `select` as a variable

Comment: It won't cause any problems whatsoever in this case, and the suggestion that some of those words should have been reserved is completely laughable

Comment: @Alnitak :  _In addition to the above reserved words, you'd better avoid the following identifiers as names of JavaScript variables. These are predefined names of implementation-dependent JavaScript objects, methods, or properties (and, arguably, some should have been reserved words):_ Taken from : http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Comment: That is _one person's opinion_ and has no sound justification that I know of

Comment: @Alnitak http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616270/onchange-event-handler-not-working ... I think `select` have some special meaning

Comment: @Alnitak :  I got it now.... using a local variable doesn't cause any problem.... but I think it's better to avoid defining `select` as a global variable

Answer (score 0):

```
Html part :
 <select id="main">

 </select>

 Jquery Part:


  var opt = ' <option selected>1</option>';
  for(var i = 2; i<= 10; i++){
    opt += ' <option>' + i + '</option>';

  }
  $("#main").append(opt);
```

Jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/v1yyhfm8/